# What is a Placeholder texture?

Tags: graphics, textures, game-engine

I am new to gaming and graphics. I came across the the tag "placeholder texture", but didn't quite understand the term.

Can someone explain me on that?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that a placeholder texture is a texture that is used to represent the final texture if it is not available, or has not been created by the developer.

Placeholder textures can be used as a stand in for a texture that a developer has not created or obtained until the final texture is available.

If anybody can come up with a better way of putting it, please feel free to edit this post.

Answer (score 0):

A placeholder texture in game design is a texture (an image used to color the various parts of a rendered scene) that is used for things that don't yet have a dedicated texture or are not meant to be seen at all. It is often very brightly colored so that during design and testing you can easily see what you might have missed such as holes in a level or just not completed. A lot of developers also choose a neutral color for it once the game is released so that mistakes are less visible to end users.